# How to place a rendered element in a div in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJs and I only know a few things as of now. I'm trying to create this Google map with directions which is successful

MapRender.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Map from './mapProps';
//import './style.css';

const googleMapsApiKey = "API_KEY";

export default function FinalMap() {

const FinalMap = props => {
  const {places} = props;

  const {
    loadingElement,
    containerElement,
    mapElement,
    defaultCenter,
    defaultZoom
  } = props;

 return (
    <Map
      googleMapURL={
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
        googleMapsApiKey +
        '&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
      }
      markers={places}
      loadingElement={loadingElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      containerElement={containerElement || <div style={{height: "80vh"}}/>}
      mapElement={mapElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      defaultCenter={defaultCenter || {lat: 25.798939, lng: -80.291409}}
      defaultZoom={defaultZoom || 13}
    />
  );
};


const places = [
  {latitude:14.7539407,longitude:121.0338431},
  {latitude:  14.625981794368357,longitude: 121.06170033978614},
]

render(<FinalMap defaultZoom={12} places={places} />, document.getElementById('root'));


}
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import picture1 from '../../src/picture1.jpg';
import RechartBar from '../postlist/Rechart-Bar';
import RechartLine from '../postlist/Rechart-Line';
import driverstat from '../driverprofiles/driverstat';
import AppMap from './Maps/map';
import MapRender from './Maps/MapRender';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="Bodydiv">
    <div className="homediv">
      <div className="userdiv">
      <div className="userdiv-profile">
        <div className="userdiv-profile-photo">
        <img src={picture1} className="photo" alt="picture1"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Name:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Driver ID:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Plate Number:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Status:
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="userdiv-stats">
        Statistics
        {driverstat.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                      {item.icon}
                  </li>
                );
              })}
              <h4 class="view-history">View History</h4>
        <input type="button" className="backtodrivers-btn" alt="back" value="Back"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className='mapdiv'>
    <MapRender/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <RechartBar/>
    <RechartLine/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The problem is It does run but it made my other elements go away because the map was rendered as seen in the last part of my MapRender.js, what I wanted to do is place this in a component and then call that component in my App.js (Similar to what I have done in RechartBar and RechartLine at the end of my App.js.

Thanks

Comment: What elements have gone away? Are you sure the map isn't just overlaying content rendered before it in the DOM?

Comment: You should just render the map component directly, you don't need to manually append it to the DOM with `react-dom`'s "render"

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing entire app with `FinalMap` component using this line.

Remove this line from MapRenderer.js

```js
render(<FinalMap defaultZoom={12} places={places} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Map from './mapProps';
//import './style.css';

const googleMapsApiKey = "API_KEY";

export default function FinalMap(props) {

  const {
    places,
    loadingElement,
    containerElement,
    mapElement,
    defaultCenter,
    defaultZoom
  } = props;

 return (
    <Map
      googleMapURL={
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
        googleMapsApiKey +
        '&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
      }
      markers={places}
      loadingElement={loadingElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      containerElement={containerElement || <div style={{height: "80vh"}}/>}
      mapElement={mapElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
      defaultCenter={defaultCenter || {lat: 25.798939, lng: -80.291409}}
      defaultZoom={defaultZoom || 13}
    />
  );
};
```

Then in App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import picture1 from '../../src/picture1.jpg';
import RechartBar from '../postlist/Rechart-Bar';
import RechartLine from '../postlist/Rechart-Line';
import driverstat from '../driverprofiles/driverstat';
import AppMap from './Maps/map';
import MapRender from './Maps/MapRender';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="Bodydiv">
    <div className="homediv">
      <div className="userdiv">
      <div className="userdiv-profile">
        <div className="userdiv-profile-photo">
        <img src={picture1} className="photo" alt="picture1"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Name:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Driver ID:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Plate Number:
        </div>
        <div className="userdiv-profile-name">
            Status:
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="userdiv-stats">
        Statistics
        {driverstat.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                      {item.icon}
                  </li>
                );
              })}
              <h4 class="view-history">View History</h4>
        <input type="button" className="backtodrivers-btn" alt="back" value="Back"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className='mapdiv'>
    <MapRender places={[
         {latitude:14.7539407,longitude:121.0338431},
        {latitude:  14.625981794368357,longitude: 121.06170033978614},
     ]}/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <RechartBar/>
    <RechartLine/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I have actually tried a number of possible solutions and this is one of it and unfortunately the page just went blank when I did this.

Comment: Which file is rendering react to DOM? can you please share that, if you are still facing the issue

Comment: Hi! If it would be any help I was actually wrong in the filename. The App.js above is suppose to be Home.js. My App.js is just composed of routers/switch for navigation.

To answer your question, I'm rendering using the default index.js that renders App.js which is just the same
<React.Strictmode>
<App/>
</React.Strictmode>

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, after making suggested changes, page is blank. check your console for any errors, it seems that app is crashing. and make sure that you are on correct route